# When and where, exactly, did the concept of a male god eating grapes orginate?

Tags: ancient-history, roman-empire, ancient-greece, greek-mythology

[image]

I am sure you have seen, somewhere, of a male god eating grapes or in some classical romantic settings, a half-naked woman putting grapes in the mouth of a half-naked man. I am very curious, where and when did this concept originate?

Comment: This might be more suited to [Mythology.SE](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HistoryStackIsLaughablyBad no, this focuses more on the cultural and historical origination of the imagery. thus it would be equally suited for either.

Comment: @tox123 That was a two year old comment. It did not need a reply.

Answer (score 8):

The god in question is [Dionysus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysus) (or Bacchus, if you're from Rome), god of the grape harvest and wine, among other things.

The geographical origins of Dionysus are Greek. From the Mycenaean Linear B tablets, we know that a "DI-WO-NI-SO-JO" was known (at least) in Pylos before 1200 B.C. ([source](http://www.csun.edu/~hcfll004/dionysos.html))

Homer's relative neglect of Dionysus, [coupled with the location of his cult-places](http://www.csun.edu/~hcfll004/dionysos.html), had once led [some to speculate](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/d/dionysus.html) that Dionysus "is in fact a fusion of a local Greek nature god, and another more potent god imported rather late in Greek pre-history from Phrygia (the central area of modern day Turkey) or Thrace."

Whatever the truth of these claims, the grape-nature-intoxication aspects of Dionysus wouldn't have come from his [possible Phyrigian aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabazios), so some kind of Dionysus-with-grapes was likely a part of Bronze Age Greek religious belief long before the Homeric epics.

Comment: Pantheon is a very bad source for this. Dionysus was mentioned in Mycenaean texts.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: Thanks! Please let me know if I have anything else wrong--or of course, feel free to leave your own (probably better) answer :)

Comment: You're probably accurate, insofar as current scholarship goes. There's a debate still, but it should fully suffice as an answer to the question.

Comment: So are the modern cinematic depictions of Roman and/or Greek Emperors eating grapes a reference to that myth? I always thought the depictions are because grapes were either luxourious or common in the Mediterranean lands at those times.